# C# winforms RichTextBox Coloration

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm sure it is something stupid I'm missing here but it's been few years since I last used winforms extensively and I can't figure this.
I want to write to a richTextBox with different color every time - like this:

```
    private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Legend != null)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Color> kvp in Legend)
            {
                writeColor(kvp.Key, richTextBoxLegend, kvp.Value, true);
            }
        }
    }
    private void writeColor(string text, RichTextBox rtb, Color c, bool newLine = false)
    {
        if (newLine && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(rtb.Text)) rtb.Text += Environment.NewLine;
        rtb.Text += text;

        rtb.Select(rtb.Text.Length - text.Length, text.Length);
        rtb.SelectionBackColor = c;
    }
```

So with one pair everything works fine, the colored text is added.
With two everything works fine too, a different color text is added.
With three pairs or more however, I get the entire text colored with the first selection color and just the last line with different color.

Comment: _rtb.Text += text;_ Never do this as modifying the Text property firectly  it will mess up any previous formatting. Instead use rtb.AppendText to add text, Insert, Cut, Paste, Copy to change and set the selection and then the SelectedXXX properties to format the text!

Comment: Yey, thank you, I knew it was something stupid... post as answer.

Comment: See also this [short answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28933957/richtextbox-formatting-not-correct/28934052#28934052)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably works better if you set the color before adding the text:

```
private void writeColor(string text, RichTextBox rtb, Color c, bool newLine = false) {
  if (newLine) rtb.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
  rtb.SelectionBackColor = c;
  rtb.AppendText(text);
}
```

Comment: Now the entire text is colored with the first writeColor() call color

Comment: @Nigel Not with the code I posted.